# Alguien me puede ayudar con un problema que tengo con angular 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Estoy tratando de pasar una plantilla html a angular, tengo un componente que se llama **Home** y cuando paso el código html en el componente no funciona, pero lo probe en el **Index.html** (se que no se debe hacer) y si funciona. Y lo raro la consola no me marca ningún error. Ojalá y me pueden ayudar, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Este es el repositorio por si lo quieren checar: https://github.com/Jod-Dev/udemy-angular9-practice.git

y aqui esta el .js: https://github.com/Jod-Dev/udemy-angular9-practice/blob/master/src/assets/js/boxlayout.js

Aquí esta el código de html, cuando hago click no reacciona:

````
      <div id="bl-main" class="bl-main">
        <section>
          <div class="bl-box">
            <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-about">About</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="bl-content">
            <h2>About this layout</h2>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>
              <a href="#><strong>&laquo; Previous Demo</strong></a> |
              <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=14783"><strong>Back to the Codrops Article</strong></a>
            </p>
          </div>
          <span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
        </section>
        <section id="bl-work-section">
          <div class="bl-box">
            <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-works">Works</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="bl-content">
            <h2>My Works</h2>
            <p>Mung bean maize dandelion sea lettuce catsear bunya nuts ricebean tatsoi caulie horseradish pea.</p>
            <ul id="bl-work-items">
              <li data-panel="panel-1"><a href="#"><img src="assets/images/1.jpg" /></a></li>
              <li data-panel="panel-2"><a href="#"><img src="assets/images/2.jpg" /></a></li>
              <li data-panel="panel-3"><a href="#"><img src="assets/images/3.jpg" /></a></li>
              <li data-panel="panel-4"><a href="#"><img src="assets/images/4.jpg" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            <p>Illustrations by <a href="http://dribbble.com/isaac317/click">Isaac Montemayor</a></p>
          </div>
          <span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
        </section>
        <section>
          <div class="bl-box">
            <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-blog">Blog</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="bl-content">
            <h2>My Musings</h2>
            <article>
              <h3>Being a Freelance Designer</h3>
              <p>... <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
            </article>
            <article>
              <h3>Working with Photoshop</h3>
              <p>... <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
            </article>
            <article>
              <h3>Making use of Icon Fonts</h3>
              <p>... <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
            </article>
            <article>
              <h3>Being a Freelance Designer</h3>
              <p>... <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
            </article>
            <article>
              <h3>Working with Photoshop</h3>
              <p>... <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
            </article>
            <article>
              <h3>Making use of Icon Fonts</h3>
              <p>... <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
            </article>
          </div>
          <span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
        </section>
        <section>
          <div class="bl-box">
            <h2 class="bl-icon bl-icon-contact">Contact</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="bl-content">
            <h2>Get in touch</h2>
            <p>...</p>
          </div>
          <span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
        </section>
        <!-- Panel items for the works -->
        <div class="bl-panel-items" id="bl-panel-work-items">
          <div data-panel="panel-1">
            <div>
              <img src="assets/images/1.jpg" />
              <h3>Fixie bespoke</h3>
              <p>...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-panel="panel-2">
            <div>
              <img src="assets/images/2.jpg" />
              <h3>Chillwave mustache</h3>
              <p>...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-panel="panel-3">
            <div>
              <img src="assets/images/3.jpg" />
              <h3>Austin hella</h3>
              <p>...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-panel="panel-4">
            <div>
              <img src="assets/images/4.jpg" />
              <h3>Brooklyn dreamcatcher</h3>
              <p>.../p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <nav>
            <span class="bl-next-work">&gt; Next Project</span>
            <span class="bl-icon bl-icon-close"></span>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>```
````

Comment: Saludos, mmm creo a mi parecer que necesitas explicar tu problema de otra forma (OJO mi opinión puede que otra persona comprenda bien tu problema). Lo que pasa es que no comprendo bien la parte en la que muestras el código **JS** ¿Es ese código que quieres poner en tu componente *Home*? Si es asi debes comenzar comprendiendo que Angular 9 utiliza **TypeScript** que a lo mejor tengas que traducir tu código JS a TS. Puede que me equivoque y no haya comprendido bien tu problema. Suerte ;)

Comment: Lo que quiero pasar es mi html al componente home. Pero no reacciona cuando hago los clicks.
Auqui esta mi código de html: https://github.com/Jod-Dev/udemy-angular9-practice/blob/master/src/app/components/home/home.component.html

Comment: El código *HTML* que quieres pasar esta en el repositorio que git que comentas?? seria mucho mejor que adjuntes ese código *HTML* que quieres pasar a tu *Home* en tu pregunta.

Comment: O bueno tal vez no vi bien tu código *Html* que quieres pasar es `<div id="bl-main" class="bl-main">` o ese solo es un pedazo de código.

Comment: Ya lo agregué...

Comment: ¿Por **"pasar"** te refieres a que quieres que este sea el HTML de un componente? ¿O es algo más complejo...? Para empezar, ve en la línea 11 que te faltan unas comillas `<a href="#">`, aunque no creo que eso resuelva la cuestión.

Comment: Asi es, de hecho es el código del componente Home

Comment: ok ahora lo verifico

Comment: te puedes apoyar con el link del repositorio por cualquier cosa, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Bueno creo que comprendo lo que quieres hacer, podrias revisar estas paginas para poder incluir tu JavaScript porque al parecer ese es tu problema. 1. [Incluir librerías externas en Angular](https://victorroblesweb.es/2017/11/25/incluir-librerias-externas-en-angular/), 2. [Cómo usar JavaScript externo y personalizado en Angular](https://www.techiediaries.com/use-javascript-in-angular/). Prueba incluyendo de esa forma.

Comment: Tal vez quieras replantear tu pregunta, a **incluir un archivo js en Angular** o algo así para que más gente pueda comprender el error y ayudarte en ese aspecto. De todas formas intenta realizarlo como en esas paginas y puede que ya tengas mas claro el porque no te funciona.